# Windows won't boot in UEFI mode, issue with the BCD

Tags: windows, uefi

I received a new Clevo P650SE laptop. The laptop only had a 500GB 7200RPM HDD to begin with, so yesterday I added my Samsung 840 EVO SSD. As I wanted this to now be the primary drive, I made another new installation of Windows onto here. After doing this, the system now displayed a boot manager at startup with the choice between the new Windows 10 installation on my SSD, or the old one on the HDD.

As I no longer wanted to use the HDD for running Windows, I decided it would be best to delete Windows from this drive. So I booted onto an Ubuntu USB and wiped the entire drive of its data in GParted, which included three different partitions. This seemed perfectly fine to me at the time, because I had a the new installation from the SSD showing up in the boot manager.

However, when I rebooted the machine and attempted to boot into the new installation on the SSD, it gives me this message:

> `The boot configuration data from your PC is missing or contains errors.`
>   `File: /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/BC Error code: 0xc000000f`

I have tried everything to recover the system but nothing has worked. Startup repair from my Windows USB doesn't do anything, the system reset wouldn't operate because it stated that the partition was locked.

Nothing with the Command Prompt is helping me either. I have done `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, but the last command returns the following error:

> `The requested system drive cannot be found`

I also did `bcdboot C:/Windows` but that also refused to work. I assumed the reason for this might be because the drive didn't have a letter, but when I attempted to add a letter is says:

> `The specified drive letter is not free to be assigned`

Both drives in my laptop have now been completely wiped and converted to MBR, but even with the two drives empty the original message still appears when booting my Windows USB in UEFI.

I'm kind of scared because I have only had this laptop a couple of weeks and it's already completely messed up. I can boot the Windows USB in Legacy and install Windows as normal, but of course I'm looking to have it back on UEFI as it was before.

Comment: First, **don't do anything more** until you are *confident* that what you are doing will, at the very least, not worsen the situation. Second, [edit] your question to tell us exactly how you wiped the HDD and what led you to do it that way. (The exact commands that you used and how you arrived at the specific parameters to them may very well be important.)

Comment: My gut feeling is that when you wiped the hard disk, you also wiped the EFI boot partition. If that's the case, then it should be possible to simply unplug the HDD, reinstall Windows on the SSD, and then reconnect the HDD.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the response, i didn't notice your comment here to begin with. That's what i believe happened as well, because from what i can remember there were three partitions on the drive and i foolishly wiped all of them in GParted without thinking. I could attempt what you said about removing the hard drive, but it's quite a pain to do on this laptop so that would be a last resort really.

Comment: The purpose of disconnecting the hard drive would simply be to ensure that you don't accidentally put boot-critical data on both devices. If you are careful during the installation process, it shouldn't strictly be necessary.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I have added some more information to my original post which might help to explain the situation.

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/52515-windows-8-cant-start-due-missing-efi-partition.html#post419519

Comment: I'm wondering whether that link might hold the answer i need, it shows a tutorial for recreating the EFI partition on the hard drive.